# Using Node.JS statements inside of PEG.js grammar

Tags: javascript, node.js, parsing, peg, pegjs

In my grammar rule i need to check whether directory exists. 
However, seems i'm unable to use `Node.JS`-specific code in grammar JS. 
Is it correct? Any workaround? 
Thanks and sorry if a question was a silly one :)

Example grammar:

```
{
    var fs = require('fs');

    function isDirectoryExists(dir) {
        return fs.existsSync(path);
    }
}

Main = "stub"
```

Output from the PEG.js [online playground](https://pegjs.org/online):

```
require is not defined
```

Comment: Surely it doesn't work in the playground because the playground runs in your browser, not in Node environment. Have you tried compiling this locally with Node?

Comment: @noppa Yes, this code really works in Node.JS environment, but not in browser! Sorry for such a stupid mistake :( Should i remove this "question"?

Comment: You can answer it yourself :) Maybe it'll help someone else, it's not a stupid mistake.

Comment: Got it. Done :)

Answer (score 1):

`Node.JS`-specific code perfectly works in Node environment on the host.
But not in my browser, there is no Node there.

So, `PEG.JS` online playground can execute only vanilla JavaScript code. 
But this is a limitation of browser, not a PEG.js.